# Reassociating trees in Template Haskell AST's

Tags: haskell, ghc, operator-precedence, infix-notation, template-haskell

I'm upgrading a library where I translate Haskell to another language. Right now I'm using [Meta.Parse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta-0.0.3.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Meta-Parse.html) to read in a Haskell module, and get back its TemplateHaskell AST, as described [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.8.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html).

The problem I'm running into is that, when I run the parse, I get a bunch of infix operators parsed as UInfixE and UInfixP, meaning that they are of unresolved associativity.

The [description of the associativity](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.8.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#infix) talks about how the Haskell compiler resolves these.

I'm wondering, is there a function avaliable which can do this reassociation on the trees I get from parsing? I'm looking for something like this:

```
reassoc :: [Dec] -> [Dec]
```

I could write the massive AST traversal that does this, but it seems like it would be a massive amount of boilerplate, and clearly the function already exists in some form (hopefully in a form that plays nice with TH).

Does such a thing exist? Is there an easy way to get rid of unresolved infix operators in the AST I get from parsing declarations?

EDIT: Even a function which, given the Name of an operator, could give its precedence and associativity, would be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if such a function exists, but you can write one yourself, using [Scrap Your Boilerplate](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scrap_your_boilerplate) to get rid of all the boilerplate code. In particular, writing a function that gets applied to every `UInfixE` (when traversing a declaration top-down) is easy:

```
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Data.Data
import Data.Generics.Schemes
import Data.Generics.Aliases

fixity :: (Data a)
       => (Exp -> Exp -> Exp -> Exp)    -- ^ a function that converts
                                        -- UInfixE Exp Exp Exp to another Exp
       -> a -> a
fixity f = everywhere' (mkT expf)
  where
    expf (UInfixE l o r) = f l o r
    expf e               = e
```

`fixity` can be applied to anything that has the type `Data`, including `Dec`, `Exp` and other TH data types.

You probably don't care about the order of `UInfixE`, as the tree is ambiguous anyway and needs to be re-associated anyway. Going a bit further in this direction, we can enhance the function to fold over every tree of `UInfixE`s it finds:

```
-- | Converts all `UInfixU` subtrees using given right-folding functions.
--
-- For example if @fixityFold step right result@ finds
-- @1 + 2 * 3 / 4@ somewhere,
-- the corresponding subtree will be replaced by (abusing the notation)
-- @result (step '1 '+ (step '2 '* (step '3 '/ (right '4))))@.
fixityFold :: (Data a)
           => (Exp -> Exp -> a -> a)
           -> (Exp -> a)
           -> (a -> Exp)
           -> a -> a
fixityFold step right result = everywhere' (mkT expf)
  where
    expf exp@(UInfixE _ _ _) = result (foldrUInfixE exp right)
    expf e                   = e
    foldrUInfixE (UInfixE l o r) rf = foldrUInfixE l
                                        (\e -> step e o (foldrUInfixE r rf))
    foldrUInfixE exp             rf = rf exp
```

This should allow you to build whatever tree-like structure you need to re-arrange the expression using appropriate precedences.